# openpyxl - get formula and value at the same time?

Tags: openpyxl

Is there any way to get both the cell formula and the cell value in the same load of the file in openpyxl?

Currently I have had to do the following:

```
wb_data_only = load_workbook(filename=file, data_only=True, read_only=True)
wb_formulas = load_workbook(filename=file, data_only=False, read_only=True)
```

And then I have to loop over the both these objects linearly in order to get the formula and value. For e.g. to get the data values only I do this:

```
for sheet in wb_data_only:
 for row in sheet.iter_rows():
   cell in row:
    return cell.value
```

And then I have to repeat the same on the formula object.

Is there a more efficient way?

Comment: No, this is already very effiicient.